# Is there any way to auto-terminate VS Code tasks?

Tags: build, visual-studio-code

I am trying to migrate a C++ project to VS Code and I found tasks to be very annoying in the fact that they don't close automatically (and I haven't found a way to do that through the settings). Thing is, my project has a shell script that builds everything and I would like to have that available with a keyboard shortcut as a single run task... just like a normal IDE builds projects.

Is there any way to have tasks auto-terminate when the script finishes?